# How to copy jar in libs folder using Intellij plugin development APIs

Tags: java, plugins, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am developing intellij plugin, on click of menu option it should copy jar to libs folder of select project. kindly provide any link or code how I can implement this.

jar is on this path "project_name\resources\raw\xyz.jar" and using below code to get that jar as inputsream but getting "NULL"

```
ClassLoader CLDR = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
InputStream is =  CLDR.getResourceAsStream("raw/xyz.jar");
```

Comment: Could you post the code that you've tried?

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight i have added the code in question

Comment: can please help me by telling how exactly u solved it.
Please send the code to paste the jar in libs folder of a project

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
PluginId runtimePluginId = PluginManager.getPluginByClassName("com.company.AnyClassInYourPlugin");
IdeaPluginDescriptor runtimePlugin = PluginManager.getPlugin(runtimePluginId);
File yourJar = new File(runtimePlugin.getPath().getAbsolutePath(), "your-file.jar");
```

Given any class that's contained in your plugin, the API allows you to retrieve a plugin descriptor for that plugin, which then allows you to get the absolute path to the plugin or any jar related to it.

See this [real example](https://github.com/ceylon/ceylon-ide-intellij/pull/62/files) of how to retrieve a JAR embedded in a plugin.

Comment: @Bastien Can you please help me with the code to paste the obtained jar i e. File yourJar  to the libs folder of android project.